# M1 macOS node-gyp build architecture problem

Tags: node.js, xcode, electron, node-gyp, apple-m1

After installing the latest xcode and bigsur updates, my node-gyp build architecture somehow locked to darwin x64 and I can not get build anymore because my project libraries do not support arm64, previously it was working with node-gyp arch darwin x64 and everything was well.

**What I tried:**

1. Re-install the node.js (14.17.0)
2. Try the get build with different node.js versions (12.21.0, 14.16.1)
3. Try to change the default build arch of the code (couldn't find where to change)

**What I want:**
When run the command of node-gyp configure want to see default build architecture back to darwin x64

"gyp info using node@14.16.1 | darwin | x64"

Comment: For the things which u mentioned in "What I tried:", if u can post the steps/methods which u followed for the same, it will be helpful to answer. Thanks.

Comment: I have very same error

Comment: did you solve it?